# Flexible flat cable labels

Tags: touchpad, cable, asus-laptop

I have a problem with an FFC that connects touchpad with a motherboard. It's **Xinya E315127 AWM 20696 80C 30V VW-1 HF** and I was wondering if someone can explain to me what do these labels on cable represent? Also, are there any recommendations as a replacement in case I can't find the exact same one?

Comment: You'd likely need to email the manufacturer to understand what each part of the model number means, however 80C may refer to max temp in Celsius; 30V may refer to voltage; HF could stand for High-Frequency, but is likely just a portion of the manufacturer's internal naming scheme.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand the labels would be contact technical person of that brand. They would be willing to help.